# Boost Date_time How to construct given a string and a format

Tags: datetime, boost

I have a string which is a date specified using a specific format string.
I would like to create a Boost `Date_Time` from it.

IO can of course use the format `string` to create a facet which I can then use in a `stringstream`, but that seems so convoluted. Is there a better way?

Comment: See the documentation http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#date_time.io_tutorial

Comment: There's no type `Date_Time` in boost. There might be a better way but you fail to provide any relevant information (like, you know, what the input format might be, or what actual type is desired)